# js function comparison with objects

Tags: javascript, object

In this JavaScript code , why the two functions when compared directly returns True while when compared using new object creation returns False?

```js
function A() {
    return this;
}

function B() {
    return this;
}

console.log(A() === B());
console.log(new A() == new B());
```

Comment: Because you cannot compare two objects in javascript. There is no native method to compare two objects, you have to write it your own.

Comment: Read from here, you will know what happens I guess. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects

Answer (score 3):

You should be aware that in JavaScript, `this` refers to the calling context or the place where the call to the function was made.

When you do

```
function A() {
    return this;
}
```

then

```
console.log( A() );
```

The calling context, for obvious reasons, is the `window` context and hence, `this` refers to `window`. Same is the case with `B()`.

However, when you do `new A()`, you initialize a new instance of the class and, vis-a-vis, a new memory location. Since each new initialization refers to a new memory location, they never equate to `true`.

Answer (score 2):

In first case `this` inside the function refers to the `window` object. So it is basically `window === window` which is true

```
function A() {
 return this;  // this is the window object
}

function B() {
  return this; // this is window object
}
```

In this case `new A()` `and new B()` refers to the different memory location, so they are never equal

Comment: So basically when I had created object of new function A and B, they both are stored in different location and refer to different objects?or are they just created at different location but are same objects!?

Comment: They are in different locations but are of the same `class`. They have the same set of parameters and initial states, but while `A` is at say `0xAA22`, `B` might be at `0xAA21`.

Comment: Okay.Got that.!